# How can a user become a non-owner of a chat room?

Tags: support, chat, owner

I observed that a user previously was among the owners of a chat room, but after some time, s/he disappeared from the owners list.

How can that happen?

Answer (score 7):

Any room owner can add or remove owners to/from the room, including themselves.

So my first guess is that they didn't want to be owner anymore; I guess you could ask them.

There's no automatic removal of room owners, so someone must have clicked a button.

**Edit:** Changing an owner (i.e. adding/removing a user from that list) is important enough for everyone in the room to know, so from now on, an automatic message will be posted into the room when that happens.

Comment: that's weird. If there's a conflict between two owners, basically the situation is like "I better unown him, so he can't unown me first"?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: If it comes that far, I would assume someone calls in a moderator (who can obviously add or remove room owners in any room).

Comment: @balpha it would be good if there are notifications for the user being removed as an owner. It appears someone removed me from the "owner" list of  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec and I didn't have any clue until someone else wondered about me not being on the list anymore. I would have liked some sort of notification. What is the rationale for allowing owners to unown other owners? IMO, people should need to approve their ownership (noone asked me to become an owner actually, someone just added), and users need to approve to be unowned by other owners (not by mods of course).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Regarding notification; I see your point (the change does indeed appear on the replies tab of your profile, but that of course only shows the last so-many events, and is not a regularly visited place). Probably wouldn't hurt to display that in the room, for everyone. Regarding rationale -- it's an owner's privilege to appoint owners, and it's their privilege to revoke that status again. There's no such thing as a super-owner.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: As to why you were removed from the list -- Fred Nurk did that, so you'll have to ask him.

Comment: I thought it already did post that ... seems obvious in hindsight

Answer (score 3):

As came up in comments with balpha on that answer, this is about you being removed from the owners for the [Lounge](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/lounge).  I removed you because I was afraid your pranks (see discussion a little above and continuing past https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/753110#753110) might run to shenanigans with the chat room mechanics.  Of course, not being listed as an "owner" doesn't affect use of the room for chat, nor did I intend to do so.